# Substituir texto por HTML quando conter valor na DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho as div's:

```
<div class="mensagem">
   <div class="texto-mensagem">:D, :( Olá Mundo!</div>
</div>
```

Quero que o resultado imprima isso:

```
<div class="mensagem">
   <div class="texto-mensagem">
      <div class="smile-happy>":D</div>, 
      <div class="smile-sad">:(</div>  
      Olá Mundo!
   </div>
</div>
```

Na verdade quero apenas substituir o valor dos smiles `**ex**: :D :(` por um html com classes específicas para cada smile!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A melhor maneira é iterar todos os elementos alvos e substituir os smiles pelo elemento HTML com a classe correta. Aparentemente se você ira utilizar esse código para formatar o texto, então para manter o seu código mais semântico, sugiro utilizar o elemento `<span>` ao invés de `<div>`

É possível fazer com javascript puro, sem jQuery.

Utilizei arrays de forma que é possível incluir novos smiles.

```js
var textos = document.querySelectorAll('.texto-mensagem');
var smiles = [':D', ':('];
var classes = ['happy', 'sad'];
for (var i = 0; i < textos.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < smiles.length; j++) {
    var div = '<span class="smile-' + classes[j] + '">' + smiles[j] + '</span>';
    textos[i].innerHTML = textos[i].innerHTML.split(smiles[j]).join(div);
    // poderia ser feito com a função replace() mas substitui apenas a primeira ocorrência
  }
}
```

```css
.smile-happy {background: #0F0;}
.smile-sad {background: #99F;}
```

```html
<div class="mensagem">
    <div class="texto-mensagem">:D, :( Olá Mundo!</div>
    <div class="texto-mensagem">sad smile :(</div>
    <div class="texto-mensagem">vários iguais :D :D :D</div>
</div>
```